# Linux Radeon HD 7730M driver

Tags: drivers, radeon

[image]I can not find drivers for this product, and recently I have been having an error when resuming from sleep..."UVD not responding, trying to restart the VCPU!"

Is there a solution to this error?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there are native drivers you can download directly from AMD (ATI).

- http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64

[image: ss of website]

#### How I found them

If you go directly to AMD's website you can search for drivers by product model number.

- http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

[image: ss #2]

Notice the choices I put into the driver picker pulldowns to get to the download page. **NOTE:** In case the download link I provided above doesn't take you back to the same drivers.

Comment: I had attempted this exact driver before and got an error about my graphics adapter not being compatible.

Comment: @guesy66213 - I'd need more specifics about your hardware then if this isn't the correct model number to diagnose further. The command line tool `sudo lspci -vv` will show you info specific to your hardware which should help with determining this.

Comment: I thought I had it right. Anyways, here it is http://pastebin.com/fVH0gcDR

Comment: @guesy66213 - you have 2 video cards an Intel and ATI. I believe this driver is correct for what the output is showing, are you sure it's not getting confused and trying to apply the ATI driver to the Intel I915 card?

Comment: i don't know how I would tell and was unaware I had two video cards. I'm assuming the Intel is my IGPU because I know the radeon is a 2GB card.

How can I know if it is doing it wrong? I'm somewhat new to Linux, as you can tell, and just trying to learn.

Comment: @guesy66213 - sure, I buy  that. The output from `lspci -vv` shows which drivers they're using. i915 is the kernel module that Intel is using, and radeon is the mod that ATI is using. What's the actual error msgs. you get when you try to use this driver with your system?

Comment: I would post a screencap, but I am unsure of how.

Comment: @guesy66213 - add it to your Q. You can upload attached images to Q&A's.

Comment: Thanks. I had just figured out how to link to it in a comment to, was just about to post.

Question updated with image.

Comment: @guesy66213 - this thread looks related: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=154538

Comment: That ends up linking to a SU question where someone says linux now supports discrete switching. That is not what I want, and the Arch forum is very in-depth...too technological for me. 

Here is the SU article. http://superuser.com/questions/516545/how-to-get-amd-catalyst-working-on-arch-x86-64

Comment: The commands using `aticonfig` are of interest by me for you running. Do they work/do anything of consequence?

Comment: No aticonfig command and no package called "aticonfig" available.

Comment: @guesy66213 should come with the driver software.

Comment: No. Only a doc directory, a check.sh, and a .run of the installer.

Comment: The driver provided there is outdated. If @guesy66213 you're using Debian check this out: https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary#Debian_8_.22Jessie.22, if not, compile from this: http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/non-free/f/fglrx-driver/fglrx-driver_14.9+ga14.201.orig.tar.xz