# how can I build Radeon proprietary drivers for CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, radeon, proprietary-drivers

So, I am running CentOS 7 on my laptop and all seems almost OK. Now I'm trying to install the video card driver.

```
# lspci -nn
...
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Chelsea LP [Radeon HD 7730M] [1002:682f]
...
```

I have found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127714/linux-radeon-hd-7730m-driver) thread from U&L and have downloaded the zip file.

But, when I try to execute the installer with:

```
[root@giedi-prime fglrx-15.302]# sh check.sh 
Detected configuration:
Architecture: x86_64 (64-bit)
X Server: XServer 1.17.2
[root@giedi-prime fglrx-15.302]# ./amd-driver-installer-15.302-x86.x86_64.run
```

And try to build an specific package for my distro (closest option is RHEL7!) it fails and there's a log message output at `/usr/share/ati/fglrx-installer.log` that reads.

```
Check if system has the tools required for Packages Generation.
Package build failed!
Package build utility output:
./packages/RedHat/ati-packager.sh: line 221: rpmbuild: command not found
[Error] Generate Package - error generating package : RedHat/RHEL7
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing (at least) rpmbuild tool:

```
./packages/RedHat/ati-packager.sh: line 221: rpmbuild: command not found
```

This (according to [CentOS wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetupRpmBuildEnvironment)) should be in `rpm-build` package which can be installed by running `yum install rpm-build`.

Comment: I managed to build the file for installation. Thanks!